# Template reference variable as @Input() for other component

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular v5.0.1

I have this template on a component

```
<div #content>some content</div>
<some-component [content]="content"></some-component>
```

I want to pass the reference of `#content` variable to `SomeComponent` via `@Input()content` but I'm not sure what type the variable is.

From what I searched on the web it appears to be `ElementRef` so I did

```
  @Input()
  component: ElementRef;
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.component); // this prints the html element on console
    console.log(this.component.nativeElement); // this prints undefined
  }
```

but `this.component.nativeElement` is *undefined*

Doing more tests it appears that *this.component* is actually the *native element*

Doing something like this works and actually the background color is changed *(this is just for testing purposes I'm not interesting in actually changing the color this way)*

```
this.component.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

While I got this working the way I wanted I have a few question to better understand how things work.

1. Is  `#content` the native element and not the `ElementRef` ?
2. Is this the valid Angular way of passing a reference variable to another component?

If you think this approach is wrong or is a better way of doing this please provide some valid example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ngOnInit()` might be too early.
`ngAfterViewInit()` might work:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.component); // this prints the html element on console
  console.log(this.component.nativeElement); // this prints undefined
}
```

> Is  `#content` the native element and not the `ElementRef` ?

If `#content` is on a plain element, it is the `nativeElement`.
If the element hosts a component or directive, you'll get the component or directive instance.

Comment: `ngOnInit` is enough in this case. And yeah, you're right that it will be `nativeElement`

Comment: @yurzui thanks! It makes me confident if you don't find a mistake in my answer :D

Comment: It becames `ElementRef` when we define `@ViewChild('content')`. But within html it will refer to native element. Seems you have already discussed about it on github and i agree because it's strange to have different behavior.

Comment: So, how can we enforce to get the actual ElementRef always?

Comment: I don't know a way. You can wrap a component in a plain HTML element and add `#content` there and then access it's child.